# Javascript code for popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I want a javascript code for popup widow with this property:
if anybody come to my site first try to connect popup window page to server on the background (loading popup page Simultaneously with main page ).. and if the person click anywhere open popup in newtab complete...
THIS IS MY CODE::

```
<script type="text/javascript">function sc(a,b)    
{document.cookie=escape(a)+"="+escape(b)+"; path=/"}
function gc(a){var b=new RegExp(escape(a)+"=([^;]+)");
if(b.test(document.cookie+";")){b.exec(document.cookie+";");
return unescape(RegExp.$1)}else return false}
function op(){if(document.popup)return;window.open
("http://www.telepost.ir/products/view/593/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA-
%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%AA-(%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%AD-%DA%86%D8%B1%D9%85)-Tissot-
1565.html","%u0641%u0631%u0648%u0634%u06AF%u0627%u0647%20%u0627%u06CC%u0646%u062A%
u0631%u0646%u062A%u06CC%20%u062A%u0644%u0647%20%u067E%u0633%u062A","toolbar=no,sta
tusbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=1000,height=650");
document.popup=true;sc("popup","true")}
document.popup=false;document.popup=gc("popup");document.onclick=op;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest==undefined&&ActiveXObject!=undefined)window.onload=op</script>
```

Comment: What's your question? Where's the code you are having trouble with? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Nycto/PicoModal

You can use this and trigger the popup on load.  Here is a fiddle showing basic usage:
http://jsfiddle.net/nnrXD/

```
<script src="your-path-to/picoModal.js"></script>
<script>
picoModal("Ah, the pitter patter of tiny feet in huge combat boots.").show();
</script>
```